# Matrix representation of the inverse of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, diagonalization

Let $\beta$ be an ordered basis of $T$, a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. My textbook says we can represent $T$ in matrix form as $[T]_{\beta}$. If $T$ is invertible, then we can write the inverse $T^{-1}$.

We can write it in matrix form as $[T^{-1}]_{\beta}$.

Could we say that $[T^{-1}] = [T]^{-1}$? (I had to remove the $\beta$ subscript for this last line because the latex was acting up, but imagine it is still there).

---

For context, I am trying to solve a problem that asks us to prove if an invertible linear operator $T$ was diagonalizable, then $T^{-1}$ is diagonalizable. If $T$ is diagonalizable, we can write its matrix representation $[T]_\beta$ as similar to a diagonal matrix :

$$[T]_{\beta} = Q^{-1}BQ$$

where $Q$ is an invertible matrix and $B$ is a diagonal matrix. I want to take inverse of both sides, which is where I get stuck for the question above about if I can say that $[T^{-1}] = [T]^{-1}$.

Comment: Is $T : V \to V$?

Comment: @0XLR Yes, $T : V \rightarrow V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your assertion is true and to see this you can make use of a very general statement about linear transformations and their associated matrix representations:

Let $U, V, W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces with bases $\beta, \gamma, \delta$. Let $F : U \to V$, $G : V \to W$ be linear transformations with matrices $[F]_\beta^\gamma, [G]_\gamma^\delta$ with respect to those bases. Then the following equation relates linear composition to matrix multiplication:
$$
[G \circ F]_\beta^\delta = [G]_\gamma^\delta[F]_\beta^\gamma
$$

In particular for your case let $U = V = W$ and $F = T$, $G = T^{-1}$. And of course, in this case, the notation $[T]_\beta$ is a simplification of the more explicit notation $[T]_\beta^\beta$. Now using the above equation, do you see why $([T]_\beta)^{-1} = [T^{-1}]_\beta$?

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now. If we let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be invertible linear operator, then we could write $[T^{-1}T]_\beta = [I_V]$. Then if we rewrite that as $[T^{-1}]$ $[T]$ = $[I_V]$, and multiply both sides by $[T]^{-1}$. Then $[T^{-1}]$ = $[I_V]$ $[T]^{-1}$, which is just the same as $[T^{-1}]$ = $[T]^{-1}$. Is that the right way to think of it? (Note: removed the subscript of beta because it was giving me trouble, but it is still there)

Comment: @Cloud Yes that's the idea indeed.